# How to launch reactJS app with google-react-maps on AWS

Tags: reactjs

When deploying reactJS project from github to AWS I have following error:

*Error: Cannot find module 'react-google-maps'

▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed. ...etc*

Does anyone knows how to resolve this problem? I assume that this is due to the fact that there is no google-react-maps preinstalled in AWS, because on local host everything is just perfect.

Comment: how are you deploying it? are you remember to run `npm install` in aws?

Comment: Do you mind to tell, how can I run it there?
I understand how to do that for local project, but not for AWS,

Comment: it depends on what aws service you are using and how you are intending on deploying it.

Comment: I create Elastic Beanstalk enivrement and use Code pipeline to deploy the project from github.

Comment: can you be more specific? what does your deploy pipeline do? does it call `npm install` and `npm build`?

Comment: None of these, Im afraid. I just followed instrudtion from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0p4dxuwv1s (from 24:30).  I create new  Web serwer enviroment with node.JS platform. Then I create pipline, where attach my project from github.
At first I managed to succesfuly launch simple reactJS "Hello-world" project, but when tried my project with google-react-maps - failed.

Comment: are you doing this just for fun? do you have a node server doing anything? maybe stick with something very easy for now like netlify. https://www.netlify.com/ you just put your build command `npm run build` in the build command field and it will install your dependencies for you and host and stuff

Comment: Nope, unfortunatly. I have this task at the uni, but since I have economy as my major and 0 coding exp, I struggle a lot and have already spent couple full days. :/ The point of the task is creat reactJS based map and to map the specific points. I finally managed to complete code and launch it on local host, but I need to upload it to aws via github.

Comment: aws is a requirement? try setting it up with netlify, it's free super fast and uses github to deploy

Comment: Yes, one of the tasks was to create aws account, since all the projects are done there. Thx for the link tho. : ]

Comment: Actually I tried the weblink, you've sent and it is much easier than aws! However still returns mistake, when building the website with google-react-maps (but works just fine on basic stuff).

Comment: is google-react-maps missing from your package.json?

Comment: I think yes, there is nothing there with google-react-maps wording.

Comment: then you need to add the package. `npm install google-react-maps` . you must have installed it locally somehow if it's working on your local machine

Comment: Geez! This actually helped me to launch the project both on netlify,com and aws!!! Thank you!